# Error in nested SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me fix this SQL statement?  I have 2 tables... trying to get a list of all records in table 1 (c) along with a count (if any) of matching records in table 2 (cp_docs).

```
SELECT TOP 100 c.cal_procedure ,           
c.description ,           
c.active ,           
c.create_user ,           
c.create_date ,           
c.edit_user ,           
c.edit_date ,           
c.id,
cp_docs.cpd     
FROM cal_procedure c
OUTTER JOIN  (select cal_procedure as cp, count(id) as cpd
from cal_procedure_doc
group by cal_procedure) cp_docs
ON cp_docs.cp = c.cal_procedure
```

Thanks,
Tracy

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error message as well as tag the appropriate RDBMS.

Comment: `OUTTER JOIN`.  You've misspelled "OUTER" and haven't specified if the join is a LEFT OUTER JOIN or a RIGHT OUTER JOIN or a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100  ` will only return 100 rows, you should use `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT`, or remove the `TOP 100` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a subquery to the SELECT clause. It's cleaner than joining a temp table. If you try to read someone else's query to figure out how a calculation is done, you'll start with the SELECT statement. If the select statement points you to a table alias (e.g. cp_docs), you need to find the table in the FROM clause... etc. The execution plans are almost identical; the proposed SELECT clause subquery actually eliminates one innocuous Compute Scaler step.

```
SELECT c.cal_procedure ,           
c.description ,           
c.active ,           
c.create_user ,           
c.create_date ,           
c.edit_user ,           
c.edit_date ,           
c.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cal_procedure_docs where cal_procedure = c.cal_procedure) AS cpd
FROM cal_procedure c
```

Comment: Thanks @Darryls99

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without the error message but your outer join has a couple issues.

1. OUTER is incorrectly written at OUTTER
2. Your OUTER keyword needs to be prefixed with LEFT OR RIGHT.  With the logic in your query you want likely want LEFT

Fixed SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 100 c.cal_procedure ,           
    c.description ,           
    c.active ,           
    c.create_user ,           
    c.create_date ,           
    c.edit_user ,           
    c.edit_date ,           
    c.id,
    cp_docs.cpd     
    FROM cal_procedure c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (select cal_procedure as cp, count(id) as cpd
    from cal_procedure_doc
    group by cal_procedure) cp_docs
    ON cp_docs.cp = c.cal_procedure
```

Now in your query, you could get null values in the cpd column if there were no values in the cal_prodcedure_doc table.  If you look at Max's answer, you would get 0's instead.  If you wanted to use your current approach but have the zero's display you would need to wrap cp_docs.cpd in a coalesce function

```
coalesce(cp_docs.cpd, 0)
```

In the end I think Max's answer is easier to read and probably the way I would write this query as I think it's easier to read.  If the tables are huge you may want to check how each performs to see one is better than the other.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick response!  Spelling matters for sure!  I'm going to use Max's solution, but your's definitely works too.

Comment: This is more in the spirit of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `outer apply` :

```
SELECT TOP 100 c.cal_procedure, c.description, c.active, c.create_user,           
       c.create_date, c.edit_user, c.edit_date, c.id, cp_docs.cpd     
FROM cal_procedure c OUTER APPLY  
     (select count(id) as cpd
      from cal_procedure_doc
      where cal_procedure = c.cal_procedure
     ) cp_docs
ORDER BY ? ? ? ;
```

Comment: This is another great idea!  Thanks for taking the time to respond.